# What API does facebook use for displaying the full Wikipedia articles?

Tags: facebook, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I couldn't find any api that return the article in a usable HTML form. Most of them return extracts which have very poor HTML formatting which makes them useless for anything.

Comment: Why are you positive that the browser is fetching the data directly from Wikipedia?

Comment: I think it was a bad assumption. All the requests are send to Facebook for getting the data. But still which API does the Facebook servers use for processing the articles?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download I would assume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to tell what Facebook did exactly, but the easiest way to grab the HTML contents of an article is by using the [`render` action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Actions), i.e. by appending `action=render` to the URL:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking?action=render

This produces the exact same HTML you can see on Wikipedia, but omits the non-content part (sidebar etc). If you need to reproduce the layout of an article more faithfully, you need to reuse parts of Wikipedia's CSS, and there is no easy way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since just a few days there is a REST API for getting the html. It is available at https://rest.wikimedia.org/

Since it is so new, Facebook is probably not using it (yet) but if you want to get it for yourself I suggest you start exploring there.

Comment: It's not the one Facebook using but it solved my problem. Thanks